# My Class becomes empty on Form Post in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm currently studying Object Oriented Programming (OOP) in C# and recently saw that Composition is favored over Inheritance due to flexibility. Anyways I'm currently stock right now.

I have 2 Class (Student and Assessment)

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class SkillsAssessment
{
    public readonly Student Student = new Student();

    [Required]
    public string Industry { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string YearsInIndustry { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Razor View StudentDetails.cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Student.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @required = "required" }) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Student.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @required = "required" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Industry, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @required = "required" }) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.YearsInIndustry, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-lg", @required = "required" })
```

And in my Controller

```
Public ActionResult(SkillsAssessment data){
    //This is where the problem comes
    //Because the Student Class inside my SkillsAssessment is always null
    //And all I can get is the Industry and YearsInIndustry field
}
```

I hope you can help me identify how to resolve this and give me clear understanding about my implementation with Composition.

Comment: It needs to be a property, not a field - `public Student Student { get; set; }` (side note: remove `@required="required"` and use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(...)`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi Sir, I apologize if this is a duplicate question can you please send me the link of the other one? also your solution to my problem actually works although I'm not really confused with the topic that I saw Composition over Inheritance. I thought I'm doing the composition correct.

Comment: What do you mean _link of the other one_? (which other one are you referring to?)

Comment: Just saw that you marked my question as duplicate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a model to the view heading
@model Student

and remove the readonly from the initialization of the class

public class SkillsAssessment
{

```
public Student _student {get;set;}
[Required]
public string Industry { get; set; }
[Required]
public string YearsInIndustry { get; set; }
```

}

then initialize the Student class in your action before sending it to the view.

Comment: Yup, I already have a @model in my View that is why I can get the value of Industry and YearsInIndustry field except only for the fields inside the student class.

Cause when the code goes to the Controller the Student class gets re-initialize that is why it becomes empty again. I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: @jmaghuyop Please check the answer i have updated it

Comment: I've already solved this problem using the one you suggest, I'm just curious now if it still follows the Composition design in Object Oriented Programming or not?

Comment: @jmaghuyop yes it does. please mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
public readonly Student Student = new Student();
```

Use

```
public Student Student = new Student();
```

`readonly` is making your property non editable

Comment: I already tried using readonly and the one you suggested still not working.  when the code goes to the Controller the Student class gets re-initialize that is why it becomes empty again. I don't know how to resolve it.